# Multiple membership providers, one user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am learning ASP.NET MVC 3 and trying to create a web application where users can upload some data and manage it.

Here is my problem:
I need to associate users to data in my database therefore I need users to have unique ids. However, users need to be able to log in from multiple membership providers (sql and ldap). So I can't assume their ProviderUserKey is unique nor can I assume what type it is.

What I need is some way to merge the users provided by the different membership providers into one user class that has unique user ids usable in my database. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do this?

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 3 framework, so I don't know if something like this already exist or not.

E: I want the business logic to be oblivious to how the user logged in. It shouldn't matter to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their **ldap email address** could provide a good unique identifier, I have used this in a similar situation.

Comment: Doesn't your business logic need to be aware how they logged in in that case?

Comment: don't see why if you're allowing them to authenticate with either provider.  what's important is that they have been authenticated to your satisfaction.

Comment: @TheTeaMan right enough anyway, I've used this quite satisfactoryily.  you only need to worry about users with multiple email addresses if you are a public facing website such as SO.  allowing only one email address seems fine, especially in my case and sounds so in yours too.  btw, to court a vote it is customary to also upvote answers you provide useful ;)  probably a bit cheeky but see you're relatively new to SO (stackoverflow) so don't feel too ashamed asking.

Comment: i remember SO automatically upvoting accepted answers (and downvoting spam questions/answers)... weird. voted up